# How do I remove Evolution from indicator-message?

Tags: unity, 14.10, evolution, indicator-message

The indicator-message (envelope icon) on Unity panel shows Evolution and Unity mail but I want it to show Unity mail only. I don't want to remove Evolution. I just want Unity mail in indicator-message and nothing else. I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with Unity.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please make clear by editing your question to include what you are trying to do, what the problem is (and any error messages given) and what you have tried doing.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution and you will remove the choice from the envelope menu. Make a copy first if you think you will ever want it back, or just recreate it, it just contains 
/usr/share/applications/evolution.desktop

```
sudo rm /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/evolution
```